# How can I move all even numbers to front in an array?

Tags: java, arrays

Following is the problem-

Given an array of integers as input, return an array that contains the same numbers as that in the input array, but rearranged so that all the even numbers are in front and the odds numbers are at the back. Note that the order of the even numbers and odd numbers should be maintained i.e. if an even number `n1` that appears before an even number `n2` in the input, then in the output array `n1` should appear before `n2`. The same is true for odd numbers. Also note that in this problem you should not create any new array.

What is done so far is as follows but I am unable to get the expected output.

```
public class MoveEvenToFront {

    static int[] testcase1 = {3, 5, 4, 6, 8, 9, 7, 10};

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MoveEvenToFront testInstance = new MoveEvenToFront();
        int[] result = testInstance.moveEvenToFront(testcase1);
        System.out.print("{");

        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            if (i > 0) {
                System.out.print(",");
            }
            System.out.print(result[i]);
        }
        System.out.print("}");
    }

    public int[] moveEvenToFront(int[] arr) {
        int temp = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i - 1] % 2 != 0) {
                temp = arr[i - 1];
                arr[i - 1] = arr[i];
                arr[i] = temp;
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }
}
```

The expected output for testcase `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,12}` is `{2,4,6,8,10,12,1,3,5,7}`.

Comment: This seems to be a proper question. Why the downvote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your algorithm is wrong. You are checking if `arr[i-1]` is not even and swapping it with `arr[i]`. If `arr[i]` is also odd, then you are not checking for it, and it moves to the front even when it is odd.

What you could do is

- find the first even number in the array and swap it with first index and increment the index.
- then find the second even number and swap it with second index, continue until end of array.

change the method as shown below:

```
public int[] moveEvenToFront(int[] arr){
    int temp=0;
    int a=0;
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(arr[i]%2==0){

            for (int j=i;j>a;j--){
                temp=arr[j-1];
                arr[j-1]=arr[j];
                arr[j]=temp;
            }
            a++;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help.But there is a slight problem in order of odd numbers.They should be in the order as they were in the previous array.

Comment: Oh..yeah..did not notice that...edited the answer with the new method.

Answer (score 3):

Try it straight forward:

```
public static Integer[] NUMBERS = {3,5,4,6,8,9,7,10};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(NUMBERS));
    int nextIdx = 0;
    for (int idx = 0; idx < ints.size(); idx++) {
        if (ints.get(idx) % 2 == 0) ints.add(nextIdx++, ints.remove(idx));
    }
    System.out.println(ints);
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
[4, 6, 8, 10, 3, 5, 9, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void moveEvenToFront(){
 int temp=0;
 for(int i=0;i<values.length;i++){
      for(int j=i;j<values.length;j++){
           if(values[j]%2==0){
                temp = values[i];
                values[i] = values[j];
                values[j] = temp;
           }
      }
 }
```

after creating `values[]`, the key point of solving this is identifying where there is an even number and switching with `values[0]`. and increase by 1 so that the even numbers don't disappear. Hope this helps.